# How to get environment information in Mule

Tags: mule

I need to put some production specific behavior in `mule-config.xml`. Is there a way to get environment info in mule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access all system properties via MEL. But I would rather suggest you modularize your configuration in several files (say: common-config.xml, test-config.xml, prod-config.xml) and load the right files at Mule startup based on the environment.

Comment: You're right. It'll solve the purpose without cluttering the main config file. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

And also you can create properties file for each environment and access it inside mule config file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create xml file with all the configurations and import/load the file into mule project

Answer (score 0):

In your Mule configuration file (src/main/app/app-config-file.xml), you can add the following line:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="${environment.name}.properties" />
```

${environment.name} must be a system environment variable. You need to make sure the system where you are deploying your app contains that variable. I think you can also specify it in the Maven build, if you are using Maven (clean install -Denvironment.name=test). You can try.

To test locally, right click on your project, select run as, select run configurations, click on Environment tab, add your variable "environment.name" and the value "local" (without quotation marks) and make sure your local.properties file exists in a location added to the build path. It can be src/main/app for example or in the resources folder.

Answer (score 0):

MEL has some context objects like server, mule ,application using these you can get the envinformation from #[server.env] for more info refer 
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/mule-expression-language-basic-syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can use different mule properties file like Mule-dev.properties , mule-test.properties. 
In global elements add a property placeholder :

In mule-app.properties define env= test or dev depending on the env value which you want to use.

Clean the project and deploy. Sometimes it is not able to read the env specific properties. Cleaning the project solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a properties file in you project and refer it from property place holder. it is better to add environment value in mule-app.properties file ehich is in /src/main/app

Answer (score 0):

you can have one variable like mule.env in this mule-app.properties and send value to this Property as DEV,QA,UAT,PROD from cloudhub properties and create different properties file in mule/src/app main  resources then use Properties placeholder to configure this  property file and send the value of mule-env dynamically from cloudhub

Answer (score 0):

Typically the way this is done is to delcare a property bean in which you set the environment specific value like PROD,QA,DEV or local. This environment specific value is set in mule-app.properties like mule.env=local, This needs to be set to the environment we are trying to deploy it and the API picks up the right properties file.